# jquery toggle function utilizing toggleClass

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently using this jquery to toggle open a series of divs all at once.

Jquery: (showall)

```
$("h4.toggle").toggleClass("active shown").nextAll().slideToggle("fast");
```

What I'm experiencing is if one of the single toggles is fired before hand and then someone uses the "showall", it will reverse the toggle instead of showing all the other divs. So, if the first one is open and the rest hidden, now the first one is hidden and the rest are shown.

Here's a sample of the HTML divs:

```
 <div id="section" class="legal2">

      <h4 class="dark toggle" id="alt1">Name Name</h4>

      <div class="toggling alt1 hiding">
</div></div>

...

<div id="section" class="legal2">

      <h4 class="dark toggle" id="alt15">Name Name</h4>

      <div class="toggling alt15 hiding">
</div></div>
```

I have a .toggle function on the h4 that pretty much just does this:

```
$('.'+which).toggleClass('showing').slideToggle(300);
```

Is there an easy way to make this 'show all' work? I tried using an if/else, but couldnt get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: you should put an example on jsfiddle. it would be easier to diagnose

Comment: @chrisvillanueva - I was just about to suggest that as well, a fiddle will help tremendously!

Comment: Totally didn't even think about it, and I use fiddle all day. It's a little backwards, but here's an example. http://jsfiddle.net/vCCS4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slideDown()` in place of `slideToggle` in this case.  Slide down shows the element with a sliding animation rather than toggling (shown to hidden, hidden to shown).  For elements already shown, `slideDown` just leaves them shown and does not animate them.  (There is also a `slideUp()` function in case you have a "hide All" function)

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t3aJV/)**

Similarly, use `addClass` / `removeClass` in place of `toggleClass`.

Comment: hmm, interesting. I'll try this out!

Comment: That's it! Brilliant, I knew there had to be something easy. I had all kinds of if/elses and whatnot. This is exactly it!